# Where has the forgotten password button gone?

Tags: lock-screens, locked-out

My device is running Android 5.0 Lollipop or above and I have forgotten my lock screen password. After trying multiple times without luck, I do not see an option to reset my password using my Google account credentials. Why is this option not appearing?

Comment: I'm posting this as there seems to be a lot of confusion about this new behaviour, understandably! Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This option seems to be have removed by Google in Android 5.0 and above and there is no longer an official way to reset your lock screen password.

Resetting your password using Android Device Manager also often fails as there is already a screen lock set.

Check the [locked-out tag](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out) for information that may help with your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Even Google gives [unlocking instructions](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/3388218?hl=en) only for Android Kitkat and below. For Lollipop and above, the *indirect* recommendation seems to be about resetting or erasing the device.

Chris Hoffman on How to Geek [reports](http://www.howtogeek.com/226942/what-to-do-if-you-forget-your-android-phone%E2%80%99s-pin-pattern-or-password/):

> [Screen lock resetting] feature was removed in Android 5.0. Unfortunately, this means there’s no built-in way to simply reset your pattern, PIN, or password and gain access to your phone or tablet. This does help provide additional protection to your data, however — attackers have no way of bypassing the passcode unless they actually know it.

Other than resetting through recovery, Settings app and from Google Device Manager, I found the following info worth mentioning:

> [Android’s Smart Lock](http://www.howtogeek.com/202881/use-smart-locks-in-android-5.0-and-never-unlock-your-phone-at-home-again/) feature may be able to save you. For example, let’s say you’ve set up Smart Lock on your Android phone and have it automatically log in when it’s on your home Wi-Fi. You can take your phone to that home Wi-FI network and it will automatically unlock for you, even if you can’t remember the normal unlock code.

Comment: This is a great answer! I'm sure somewhere there's a thread about possible ways to recover access to your device but I can't find it. If there is, we could link to it in addition to the info above. It has other things to try such as ADB commands.