# Moto E , Tried 55 times on Pattern lock screen

Tags: applications, lock-screens, password, pattern-lock

I changed my pattern recently. Tried it 55 times and hasn't showed "Forgotten Password' option. HELPP Moto E

Comment: Why the downvotes looks a genuine question to me ?

Comment: See [Where has the forgotten password button gone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/136377)

Answer (score 0):

**How can I fix it?**

You must factory reset the phone. There will be no pattern.

**What's a factory reset?**

It wipes all of your data (including your password)